# I get the error "The proxy server is refusing connections" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, proxy, firewall

Hello I have tried to run the java code, but it gives the error "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Web page is not opened. I have checked the proxy setting as well. It is set as auto detect

still getting the error. I checked the firewall setting also. so please let me know what should do to solve the error

This is code:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
//import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class sample_google
{

    WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeTest

    public  void setUp(){

       // FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\ashwini\\geckodriver.exe");
        
      driver= new MarionetteDriver();
         //driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    @Test

    public void testsample_google() throws Exception{

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
//        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
//        searchBox.sendKeys("fast cars");
//        searchBox.submit();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        System.out.println("Page title : " + driver.getTitle());
        WebElement resultCount = driver.findElement(By.id("resultStats"));
        System.out.println("Result Count : " + resultCount.getText());
       

    }
    @AfterTest
      public void teardown()
      {
          //driver.quit();
      }

    
}
```

And error:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Pramod\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-33059775\testng-customsuite.xml

1472721257179   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 61629
1472721260499   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser db6c37fd-5fa7-4f5e-a1fd-89f46151f221
1472721260513   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync db6c37fd-5fa7-4f5e-a1fd-89f46151f221
1472721261196   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync db6c37fd-5fa7-4f5e-a1fd-89f46151f221
FAILED: testsample_google
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample_google.testsample_google(sample_google.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 38 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5594a1b5: 31 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3f3afe78: 21 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1cd072a9: 141 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@34ce8af7: 11 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6b71769e: 54 ms
```

Comment: Can you please supply some code and more information?

Comment: sure I am adding the code

Comment: Line 45 seems to be `driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");` - are you sure `driver.findElement(By.name("q"))` is not returning `Null`? And you have followed the [instruction here](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/03/how-to-set-proxy-settings-in-selenium.html) for setting up your proxy?

Comment: yes it return the value as null as it is not able to find the element using name, hence I have tried to get it using id, name, xpath , css selector to recognize the element. so it's not wokring. so please check

Comment: I'm still not clear if the problem is with your proxy (if so, did you follow the instructions on the page I linked to?) or is it with the returned data; do you actually get a web page back from your call?

Comment: proxy issue is solve by changing the lan setting but nullpointer exception issue is not resolved yet

Comment: When i run the code the web page open up but didn't found the element where i need to enter data. it shows null pointer exception as the proxy setting i have changed and that error is solved. so please help for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue for the proxy is resolved by changing the LAN setting of my computer